# When calling CRUD check if "parent" exists with read or join?

Tags: java, sql, performance, join, get

All my entities can not be deleted - only deactivated, so they don't appear in any read methods (`SELECT ... WHERE active=TRUE)`.

Now I have some 1:M tables on this entities on which all CRUD operations can be executed.

What is more efficient or has better performance?

My first solution: To add to all CRUD operations:

`UPDATE ... JOIN entity e ...  WHERE e.active=TRUE`

My second solution: Before all CRUD operations check if entity is active:

```
if (getEntity(someId) != null) {
    //do some CRUD
}
```

In `getEntity` there's just `SELECT * FROM entity WHERE id=? AND active=TRUE`.

Or any other solution, recommendation,...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second, plus an active second level cache ;) Chance is that the object already is in memory. Chance is acutally pretty high.

Answer (score 0):

I would move all deactivated entities to a separate table and not worry about the entity being active.